# Redux Form is not firing off submit function

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have set up a redux form but it does not seem to be firing off onSubmit the actual `submitHandle` function.
Please see the code below

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { hideTransferLicenseWindow, setProgressBarValue } from "../../redux/actions/LicenseActions";
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

export class LicenseTransfer extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props)
  }

  renderInput = ({ input, customValue, autoFocus }) => {
    return (
      <input
        className="uk-input"
        {...input}
        value={customValue}
        autoFocus={autoFocus}
      />
    )
  }

  onFormSubmit = (values) => {
    console.log('Clicked submit')
  }

  render() {
    const { licenseOperations } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="app-section transfer-license-window">
        <button
          onClick={() => this.props.hideTransferLicenseWindow()}
          uk-close=""
          className="uk-alert-close"
        ></button>
        <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.onFormSubmit)}>
          <div className="field">
            <label>From:</label>
            <Field
              name="transferLicenseFromEmail"
              component={this.renderInput}
              customValue={this.props.userEmail}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="field">
            <label>To:</label>
            <Field
              name="transferLicenseToEmail"
              component={this.renderInput}
              autoFocus={true}
            />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const transferLicenseFormWrapper = reduxForm({
  form: 'transferLicense',
})(LicenseTransfer)

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    userEmail: state.user.user.email,
    licenseOperations: state.licenseOperations,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { hideTransferLicenseWindow, setProgressBarValue })(
  transferLicenseFormWrapper
);
```

So it should log form values on submitting the form but it does not react nor gives any errors/
I have similar form set up in another component which works just fine. Spent good amount of time playing the game of finding differences but this does not makes sense to me.

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your code with codesandbox? this will help us to easily trace the bug.

Comment: Makes me thing that there can only be one redux-form in the entire app, because handleSubmit does not fire off any functions (inline console.log, external functions, nothing)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.
For those who might have the same issue, make sure to place your `submit` button inside the Form, if you want to be able to submit by pressing "Enter".
If you just want to submit with a mouse click on button only, it is sufficient to leave the button outside of the form (not sure if there are any other consequences).